# Add GEOJSON layer in tilemill EACCES symlink Error

Tags: geojson, tilemill

I'm trying to add a GEOJSON layer to Tilemill [ *Version 0.10.2 (v0.10.1-293-g697c86c)* ], installed on ubuntu 14.04.  I've confirmed that the ID used is unique and attempted to load the file into my project via 'Add Layer'.

I've tried to select the file on the local file system, and after I select and click on `Save`, I get the error, `EACCES symlink [filepath]`.

This is intended to replace an existing `.shp` labels file.  In Tilemill the `.shp` file is successfully assigned and displayed, but when I put the newly created `.json` file into the layers directory where the `.shp` file is and give the `.json` file the same permissions I still get the `EACCES symlink` error.

I've even attempted to serve the file via http on localhost.  I get see that the file is retrieved with a 200, but the same error is seen.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

BTW - the geojson I'm trying to load is the output of [Dymo](https://github.com/migurski/Dymo), so I'm creating the format myself.  I've confirmed that the target json file can be loaded by python's json library, so it seems there is not a problem with the format.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bugfix relating to windows that was added to version 0.10.1](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1717) of TileMill.  The bugfix may solve Linux problems too. [This may be related to how node.js was installed on your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786565/npm-error-when-installing-globally-even-when-directories-are-writable). If you didn't know, node.js is used to run TileMill. You may have to correct the node.js installation issues to resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I forgot to mention this is on Ubuntu 14.04.  I'll look into the node.js issue, I'm pretty sure I just used `apt-get` to install tilemill.

Comment: If you look at the second link I provided, it shows some of the problems with apt-get or other installation methods that will generate the EACCESS errors. If you stuck with apt-get, then you may have to change ownership to your user verses the root user that was used with apt-get. One person suggested to look at the output of `npm -g bin`.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't see why node would only cause errors for `.json` files, while allowing `.shp` files to pass through.